# Updating Gmail drop-down suggestions

Tags: gmail-api

I have observed that when I use the Gmail API to delete a message, the deleted message still shows up in the drop-down suggestions in the search bar. If the drop-down suggestion is chosen, the UI responds with an error banner:

> The conversation no longer exists.

Is there any way to prevent the drop-down suggestion from listing entries that yield this error? Is it an issue with Gmail's search index?

Further details:

I know how to *remove* the drop-down suggestions; this is not what I want. I want it to not display deleted messages. I've also seen discussion that Gmail Offline may cause this issue. However, I have observed it happening without this feature enabled.

Comment: Was the email previously read in the browser? If it was, it may not be an API issue but was caused by caching, a related issue [Email Address Drop-down Suggestions Appears Even after Deleting](https://www.gtricks.com/gmail/email-address-drop-down-suggestions-deleting/). Hope this helps.

Comment: The mail is previously read. Also, these obsolete drop-downs are persisting 3+ months after the fact.